# Clear custom ListAdapter

Tags: android

I have a problem with my adapter. All works fine but i have a problem with clearing my list.

I clear it like this:

```
public void onResetClicked(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "reset button clicked");
    m_stopwatchService.reset();

        alist.clear();
    }
```

It doesn't work.

**EDIT**

It works but I can not re-create the list.

```
public void onResetClicked(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "reset button clicked");
    m_stopwatchService.reset();

        alist.clear();
        listView.setAdapter(null);
    }
```

It is a stopwatch. My adapter creates lap. When I press the "Reset Button" wants to clean the list of my laps.

**EDIT2**

I solved my problem.

I called it like this :

```
listView.setAdapter(null);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: what is `alist`? Your ListView or your adapter? Did you override/implement `clear` in your custom adapter? Show us more code!

Comment: if(adapter!=null){
                                listView.invalidateViews();
                            }

Answer (score 0):

Once you clear the Adapter you have to invalidate the view.

alist.clear();

listView.invalidateViews();